# QTableView::rect() and QTableView::geometry() not giving accurate results

Tags: qt, qtableview

I have a QTableView, and I need to implement some page up page down functionality.

I'm generally passing QModelIndexes to the model to figure out what it should scroll to.

```
QModelIndex top = indexAt( rect().topLeft() ); // always good (row 0)
QModelIndex btm = indexAt( rect().bottomLeft() ); // always bad (last visible row + 4);
```

I've done some fidgeting with rect().bottomLeft() to account for the horizontalScrollBar() when visible, but it's still off by 3 rows.  It's liveable, but not ideal.  I'm sure hacking it and offsetting it a static number of rows would break it when the font size is different.

Honestly I'd be fine if you could tell the QScrollBar to scroll up or down one singleStep, but apparently that makes too much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is that `rect()` of? Most likely you're asking for a wrong one. Remember that these views are scroll areas, and the `rect()` you should be concerned with is that of the `viewport()`.

Comment: Sorry that I was unclear there.  That would be QTableView::rect();

Comment: And, like magic, when I change I do viewport()->rect()->bottomLeft() it works.  Cheers.